# Is the server running on host "localhost"?

Tags: postgresql, server, pg-hba.conf

I have an issue with postgresql. I saw some posts editing pg_hba.conf but it doesn't work.

Here the issue :

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061)
        Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 32?
could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061)
        Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 32?
```

And my pg_hba.conf :

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     trust
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 trust
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
local   replication     all                                     trust
host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
host    replication     all             ::1/128                 trust
```

I don't understand what is the problem if someone can explain to me.

Comment: Is your Postgres running? Try connecting using pgAdmin or some clients.

Comment: @dassum I connected using pgAdmin 4 so I think it's running.

Comment: Did you restart or SIGHUP the postgres server after editing pg_hba.conf ?

Comment: @wildplasser Yes I did, restarted from 'Services' on Windows